# Fontawesome icons in generated pdfs in coldfusion

Tags: css, pdf, coldfusion, font-awesome

I am creating a pdf file in coldufsion like that:

```
<cfdocument marginbottom="3" margintop="0" overwrite="yes" pagetype="A4" format="#dokuArt#" filename="#docuName#" unit="cm">
    ...
    <cfif len(getDataOrder.strPhoneCustomer)>
        <span class="fontawesome">&##xf098;</span>Phone: #getData.strPhoneCustomer#<br />
    </cfif>
    <cfif len(getData.strFaxCustomer)>
        <span class="fontawesome">&##xf1ac;</span>Fax: #getData.strFaxCustomer#<br />
    </cfif>
    ...
</cfdocument>
```

CSS class:

```
.fontawesome {
    font-family: 'fontawesome';
}
```

Everything is working but the generated pdf won't show the fontawesome icons.

The font is integrated in the same css file like the fontawesome class above like that:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontawesome';
    src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
}
```

What do I need to do to get the icons shown in the pdf?

Comment: What version of ColdFusion? You would need to look up what subset CSS is supported by that version.

Comment: It is Coldfusion Version 11

Comment: I just found out that cfdocument just supports CSS 1 and CSS 2. That is the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: The new method htmltopdf is better, but it just work if you have Coldfusion 11

Comment: You could likely add a bit of.javascript before printing to solve it. See http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.GlyphIcons for a discussion how we did it in @cloudformatter

Comment: I believe you have to add the font to the server first. Then you might be able to use it w/o `@font-face`.